# C++ wrapping variable argument macros

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-functions

I want to do for example:

```
#define macro(a) foo( _blah_, *(dword*)(&a) );
#define macro(a,b) foo( _blah_, *(dword*)(&a) , *(dword*)(&b) );
#define macro(a,b,c) foo( _blah_, *(dword*)(&a) , *(dword*)(&b) , *(dword*)(&c) );
```

But of course with variable no. of arguments. I essentially want to wrap each argument indiviudally, not pass all the arguments as one `__VA_ARGS__` block.

Comment: Do we _really_ need to be using macro functions in today's world of inline functions and compilers that can generally optimise better than _any_ human that doesn't write optimisers for a living?

Comment: This looks like something that might violate strict aliasing rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As any other sane person, I advise you to drop the macros, especially with C++11's variadic templates:

```
template<class T>
dword& make_dword(T& v){
  return *reinterpret_cast<dword*>(&v);
}

template<class... Args>
void bar(Args&... args){
  foo(_blah_, make_dword(args)...);
}
```

This should do the trick.

I need to mention that those `reinterpret_cast`s look pretty dubious, though...